# Pandas DataFrame merge resets index

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, merge

I'm trying to merge two Pandas `DataFrames`, where (possibly) there are some duplicate records. The merge works as expected, but unfortunately, it seems to reset the index. Consider this simple example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

index = np.arange(10,15)
data  = np.arange(10,15)
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'data':data}, index=index)

index = np.arange(12,17)
data  = np.arange(12,17)
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'data':data}, index=index)

df3 = df1.merge(df2, how='outer')
```

This results in:

```
# df1:       df2:         df3: 
# ------     # ------     # ------
    data         data         data
10    10     12    12     0    10
11    11     13    13     1    11
12    12     14    14     2    12
13    13     15    15     3    13
14    14     16    16     4    14
                          5    15 
                          6    16
```

So the indexes in `df1` (10-14) and `df2` (12-16) have been replaced by (0-6) in the merged `df3`. Is there a logical explanation for this behavior? Why aren't the indexes in `df3` (10-16)?

The only workaround seems to be to reset the indexes in `df1` and `df2` with `.reset_index()`, do the merge, and setting the index again in `df3` with `df3.set_index('index')`, which does result in:

```
In [97]: df3.index
Out[97]: Int64Index([10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16], dtype='int64', name='index')
```

Is there a way to get to this result, without resetting and re-resetting the indexes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for `concat` rather than `merge`. Check the below:

```
In [13]: pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=0)
Out[13]: 
    data
10    10
11    11
12    12
13    13
14    14
12    12
13    13
14    14
15    15
16    16
```

Comment: probably followed with a `drop_duplicates()`

Comment: `concat`, combined with `drop_duplicates()`, does the job. But I'm still wondering why `merge()` behaves like this in my example. I'll wait a bit longer to see if anyone can explain it and/or find a clean method with `merge` that works, otherwise I'll except this as an answer

Comment: @Bart I can't comment on why merge behaves this way, but for more info you can check out the documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html). The relevant bit: "If joining columns on columns, the DataFrame indexes will be ignored. Otherwise if joining indexes on indexes or indexes on a column or columns, the index will be passed on".

Comment: I read that, but didn't find the documentation very clear. Anyhow, I'm using your solution now, it works perfectly and seems to be the shortest way of merging the data frames, so I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I would use

```
 df3.index = df3['data'].values
```

Comment: Sorry, my example was a bit too simple, this might work in this simplified case, but it won't work with my real data